# Pentaho Data Integration: convert number string without separator to decimal

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I'am reading a fixed lenght file with "Text File input" step.
In a position i have a number, let's say: `0000001234`
I need to read this number like `1,234`, with 3 decimal values.

There is an option to do that? I'have tryed with precision and decimals in the field section of the stp, but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone has a more elegant way for this, but you can do it with a calculator step (now improved per marabu's comment).

1. Make sure your input field is a number type, not an integer.
2. Add a Calculator step.
3. Configure a new field "divisor" of type "set field to constant A" and type 1000 under "Field A". Set Remove to Y.
4. Configure a second field of type "A / B", with A your data field and B the divisor field.

Comment: No need for a separate step to add the divisor, since Calculator can do that, too.  I expect a slightly better performance from a Java-Expression, though.

Comment: Learned something new again! So you can indeed create a temp field inside the calculator and set it to constant value A (enter 1000 in field A). I only tried entering 1000 directly in field B of the A / B calculation and that doesn't work.